# displaying the result of submit button on the same page in php

Tags: php

I am trying to display the results of my database search on the web page. I do not get any results when I press the submit button. However, when I put a specific value in the query code instead of the $valueToSearch variable, it finds and displays the results successfully. I believe the problem is in the submit button.
Here is the code :

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['search']))
{
    $valueToSearch = $_POST['valueToSearch'];
    $query = "SELECT * FROM volunteers WHERE fname='.$valueToSearch.'";    
    $search_result = filterTable($query);
    
}

else{
$query = "SELECT * FROM `volunteers` WHERE 1";  
$search_result = filterTable($query);
}

function filterTable($query)
{
    $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "volunteedbzlfqf");
    $filter_Result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
    return $filter_Result;
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>PHP HTML TABLE DATA SEARCH</title>
        <style>
            table,tr,th,td
            {
                border: 1px solid black;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        
        <form action="" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="valueToSearch" placeholder="Value To Search"><br><br>
            <input type="submit" name="search" value="Filter"><br><br>
            
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>الهوية</th>
                    <th>كلمة المرور</th>
                    <th>الاسم</th>
                    <th>العائلة</th>
                    <th>الجنس</th>
                    <th>الجوال</th>
                    <th>الإيميل</th>
                    <th>الميلاد</th>
                    <th>المدينة</th>
                    <th>المؤهل</th>
                    <th>التخصص</th>
                    <th>التطوع</th>
                    <th>الساعات</th>
                    <th>العضوية</th>
                    <th>النقاط</th>
                    <th>التقييم</th>
                    <th>الإنذارات</th>
                </tr>
<?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($search_result)):?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $row['id'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['password'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['fname'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['lname'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['gender'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['phone'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['email'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['DOB'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['city'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['degree'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['major'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['Vtype'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['hours'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['membership'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['points'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['rating'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['warnings'];?></td>
                </tr>
                <?php endwhile;?>
            </table>
        </form>
        
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you have a database dump to test with ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might need to just change:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM volunteers WHERE fname='.$valueToSearch.'";
```

to:

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM volunteers WHERE fname="' . $valueToSearch . '"';
```

or better yet, use something like:

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM volunteers WHERE fname= ?';
```

and parameterize that.

SELECT * FROM volunteers WHERE fname="scotti"mysqli_result Object ( [current_field] => 0 [field_count] => 15 [lengths] => [num_rows] => 1 [type] => 0 )

الهوية  كلمة المرور     الاسم   العائلة     الجنس   الجوال  الإيميل     الميلاد     المدينة     المؤهل  التخصص  التطوع  الساعات     العضوية     النقاط  التقييم     الإنذارات
1       scotti

```
CREATE TABLE `volunteers` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `password` varchar(16) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fname` varchar(16) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lname` varchar(16) DEFAULT NULL,
  `gender` varchar(16) DEFAULT NULL,
  `phone` varchar(16) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(16) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DOB` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `city` varchar(16) DEFAULT NULL,
  `degree` varchar(16) DEFAULT NULL,
  `major` varchar(16) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Vtype` varchar(16) DEFAULT NULL,
  `hours` varchar(16) DEFAULT NULL,
  `membership` varchar(16) DEFAULT NULL,
  `points` varchar(16) DEFAULT NULL,
  `rating` varchar(16) DEFAULT NULL,
  `warnings` varchar(16) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: But now how do I return to the last state (all are displayed) after I press the submit button ?

Comment: See the other answer.  You need to do something like:  if(isset($_POST['search']) && !empty(trim($_POST['valueToSearch']))) at the top of your code so that is search for all if the post is an empty string or just white space.

Comment: (isset($_POST['valueToSearch'])) will be true all of the time the way you have your code, but it will be empty.  You have to check if it is an empty string or just white space to bypass filtering the list.

Comment: I don't know Arabic, but I think you might have some of your column headers out of order ?  ID, Password, Last, Name, Gender, Mobile, Email, Birth City, Qualification, Specialization, Volunteer ,Membership, Hours, Points Rating No.  The Last & Name, and Membership & Hours might be out of order ?

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. I will try and see. The columns are not out of order, but yes their names might be confusing.

Comment: I added some SQL to create a table.  Not sure that is right, but useful.

Comment: You might want to read about PDO and prepared statements also.  There are a lot of tutorials on the web:  e.g. [PDO Prepared Statements](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access--net-12059)

Answer (score 0):

As of today, the `action` attribute, if present, must be non-empty. So you have two choices:

1. set it to the current page value: `<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">`
2. eliminate the attribute completely: `<form method="post">`

I think there's also a cleaner way to check for the POST done, and that would be based on [this excellent example at W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_superglobals_post.asp)

All in all, the code fixes you need are:

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    if (isset($_POST['valueToSearch']))
    {
        $valueToSearch = $_POST['valueToSearch'];
        $query = "SELECT * FROM volunteers WHERE fname='.$valueToSearch.'";    
        $search_result = filterTable($query);
    
    } else {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM `volunteers`";  
        $search_result = filterTable($query);
    }
}
```

and don't forget the `form` `action` parameter.